# How to combine translation and fading animations

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to rearrange the content of my UIView based on a user event (rotation), and I've found that I would like to combine a translation animation, and the fading out and fading in of various controls.

Since this seems to depend on the "options" of the animate functions, I assumed that I need to  launch two animations concurrently with different options, as follows.  The "Layout_Set" function assigns new "frames" to all of my controls, which works fine.  The "setHidden" in the block of the other animation is intended to fade out a single control on rotation.

However... doesn't work.  Is this the right way to (a) launch concurrent animations and (b) to fade out a control?

Thanks very much for any help.

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                          delay: 0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn +  
 UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut + UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{

                         [self Layout_Set];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){}];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                          delay: 0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn +   
 UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut + UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{

                         [self.UIImageQRCameraLogo setHidden:true];

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

Comment: Does it not do what you want if you move the setHidden: statement into the first animations block, and eliminate the second animateWithDuration?

Comment: Also, options are combined using bitwise or (`|`)

Comment: @rdelMar If I put the setHidden in the first animation, then it just immediately vanishes.  I want it to fade out.

Comment: @Davie I think I do that if I want multiple options to apply to one animation, correct?  In my case I want one (set of) option(s) to apply to one animation, and a different (set of) options to apply to another.  Same thing, for example, if I wanted two different "delays."  Is two separate animation calls like above the way to do that?  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, you should put self.UIImageQRCameraLogo.alpha = 0 (rather than setHidden), and that should fade out over the duration time.

Comment: @rdelmar thanks!  If I wanted the fade to happen quicker than the translation, should I package it in a separate animation command with a shorter duration, similar to above?  Is that the "right" way?

Comment: Use animateKeyframesWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:. You can add as many keyframes (addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:relativeDuration:animations:) as you want to that and give each a delay and duration with respect to the start of the overall animation.